# Put 2 images on top of each other

Tags: html, css, image, overlay

I'm currently making a Cluedo-esque style of website where people can suspect people or declare them innocent.
When I person is innocent, I want to put a red cross over their pictures.

But currently I'm struggling to position everything.
I've managed to put 2 images over each other, but not on the correct position.

Current situation: A table with pictures in the first row.
This is the CSS added to the pictures:

```
<td><img src="bottom.jpg" style="z-index: 0; position: absolute"  />
    <img src="top.png"    style="z-index: 1; position: absolute"/>
</td>
```

[image: Current situation]

How can I the position of both of my images?
Removing the "position: absolute" doesn't work, so how can I fix this and still keep both of the pictures in the table cell.

The solution should work for all the pictures in the table (a general CSS class for each of the pictures (top/bottom).

Thanks!

**EDIT after Fabio's suggestion**

It solved a part of the issue, but not entirely.
This is the current situation with the exact code you suggested:

[image: New situation]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should wrap the images by an additional `<div>` in order to use relative positioning. Because the effect of `position: relative;` on table-cell elements is undefined.

> **[9.3.1 Choosing a positioning scheme: 'position' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position)**
>
> The effect of `position:relative` on `table-row-group`, `table-header-group`,
>   `table-footer-group`, `table-row`, `table-column-group`, `table-column`,
>   `table-cell`, and `table-caption` elements is **undefined**.

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsbin.com/vopifo/2/edit)**

```
<td>
  <div class="img-container">
    <img class="top" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150" alt="">
    <img class="bottom" src="http://placehold.it/200x150/fe0" alt="">
  </div>
</td>
```

Then you could simply remove the `.top` image from document normal flow an place that over the other one as follows:

**CSS**

```css
.img-container { position: relative; }

.img-container .top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

---

<sup>PS: I've added a transition of `opacity` property in the online demo to hide `.top` images on mouse over.</sup>

Comment: additionally, in a different situation, you might want to add display: inline; to the style of the div if you intend to have a lot of div's...

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove your inline styles. If possible give classes to images, like this:

```
<td><img  class="bottomimg" src="bottom.jpg"  />
    <img  class="topimg" src="top.png" />
</td>
```

then in CSS

```
td{position:relative; z-index:0}
.bottomimg{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:1}
.topimg{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:2}
```

Comment: I just tried your code, but the problem is semi-solved. Please take a look at the edit in the OP for the current situation

Comment: @Matt **FYI**: OP stands for Original Poster :) Not the post itself.

Comment: And `td{position:relative;}` makes no sense; Refer my answer.

Comment: Woops, my bad. Thanks for telling me :-)